# Initialise template class with different template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, alias

I'm trying to create the same class from a class template with different template parameters.

Let's say I create a custom type `A` which is created via a class template

```cpp
typename <int i1, int i2>
class A { };
```

now I have a second class template `B` that takes a `A<x,y>` as its template parameter

```cpp
template <typename A_T>
class B { };
```

I could define alias template to also allow

```
template <int i1, int i2>
using BD = B<A<i1, i2>>;
```

My question is is there any way of designing this such that the template name would be the same for the user in bother cases? I.e. such that a user could do

```cpp
typedef A<1,2> A_t;
B<A_t> b1;

B<1,2> b2; // Rather than BD<1,2>;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `B<a>` won't compile. You'd want `B<decltype(a)> b1;` `B` objects can also be written to be `B<A<1, 2>>` if the template is `template <typename T>class B{};`, would that not suffice? I'm not versed enough with templates and specifically SFINAE to know for sure if what you want is possible or not. My inclination is that it's not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Edited the question to fix that part.

Comment: `B<A<1, 2>> b1; B<1, 2> b2;` is not possible, but `auto b1 = makeB<A<1, 2>>(); auto b2 = makeB<1, 2>(); static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(b1), decltype(b2)>);` is possible.

Comment: If you want `B` to be instantiated only with `A<int, int>`, you should declare but not define `B` and then specialize it for taking an `A<int, int>`

Comment: @Fareanor could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Of course :) You current `B` accepts anything as template parameter. For example you could instantiate a `B<char>` or `B<SomeClass>`. If you want to only allow `B<A<int, int>>`, you need to remove the definition of `B` and write a specialization of `B` taking what you want (`A<int, int>`). [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/8nG5WG) is an example I just wrote for you :)

Comment: Thank you. This didn't solve my main problem but is still really helpful for me. Is there a way of still having a default template i.e. `A<1,1>`?

Comment: Ah just figured it myself :-)